# no version found com.google.firebase in react-native-fcm

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native version 0.40, and followed the read me from this repo and i'm getting the following error when I try to run `react-native run-android`:

> could not find any matches for
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+ as no versions of
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging are available.

I have no clue what is the source for this error. I searched everywhere and I couldn't debug this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, i need to update the android sdk google play services and google repository.

I am using ubuntu with android sdk installed, i type android in console and updated the packages.